# Maven gives MojoExecutionException with generating Tapestry

Tags: maven, tapestry

When trying to execute the following command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=http://tapestry.apache.org.
```

I get the following error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2
.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of go
al org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate failed: Plugin o
rg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2 or one of its dependencies co
uld not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.codehaus
.groovy:groovy:jar:1.8.3, org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.8.1: Could not transfer artif
act org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:1.8.3 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apac
he.org/maven2): GET request of: org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/1.8.3/groovy-1.8.3.ja
r from central failed: Read timed out -> [Help 1]

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResoluti
onException
```

So I visited

> https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

And it says to look in the tapestry documentation what this error means, but I can't find it there. 
Thx in advance with any help I get.

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that there's a problem downloading this file:

http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/1.8.3/groovy-1.8.3.jar

I assume that it's caused by your network settings. Is there maybe any proxy settings you should consider as the root of your problem in your ~/.m2/settings.xml ?